# How to share variables real time between functions

Tags: python

I have a software engineering project (using python) with the end goal of plotting data real time. For simplicity, assume I have these two separate functions, one function to generate data, another to plot the data (that was just generated) real-time using `matplotlib`, The question is how do I have these two parallel running functions share the same variable?

I've looked into `multiprocessing`, and I have gotten both functions running simultaneously. However, I cannot get them to share data real-time. Here is what I have:

```py
import time
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random
import multiprocessing as mp


def live_graph():
    # Create figure for plotting
    fig1 = plt.figure(1)
    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    xs = []
    ys_temperature = []

    # This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
    def animate_temperature(i, xs, ys_temperature):
        # Add x and y to lists
        xs.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
        ys_temperature.append(random.randint(-55, 55))

        # Limit x and y lists to 20 items
        xs = xs[-20:]
        ys_temperature = ys_temperature[-20:]

        # Draw x and y lists
        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(xs, ys_temperature)

        # Format plot
        plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
        plt.title('Temperature over Time')
        plt.ylabel('Temperature (deg C)')

    ani_temperature = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate_temperature, fargs=(xs, ys_temperature), interval=1000)

    plt.show()


def gen_data():
    while True:
        temperature = random.randint(500, 1000)
        print(temperature)
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    one = mp.Process(target=gen_data)
    two = mp.Process(target=live_graph)

    one.start()
    two.start()
```

Right now, the `live_graph` function is just plotting arbitrary data. I want it to be plotting the data that is generated by the `gen_data` function. Any tips or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Will your gen_data function run continuously in the background? If it does, considering using thread (read) safe data types (i.e. list) and run it as a background thread accessing the same data structure.

Comment: Read about [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue)

Comment: For my project, it will run continuously for around 15 seconds. But for the next ones who continue the project after me, it will be running for hours at a time. Thanks, I will look into what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several approaches, depends on the exact problem you have:

1. Use threads instead of multiprocessing. Parallel *processes* will not share the same context so the variables will not be shared. Threads, however, allows that. But in Python you will suffer from the GIL issue, which may not be a concern if one thread is I/O bound and another is CPU bound.
2. See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes for an example of using [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) across processes. Your data is passed one-way, so a queue is sufficient.
3. Use something fancy, like a message queue server, etc. You should consider this approach if you can foresee the program to evolve to a large scale that using a multi-tier architecture makes sense.